# TIFF image from R displaying only white in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, r, geotiff-tiff, display

[image: network plot from R]

I cannot get this TIFF image, which was exported from R to display in ArcMap 10.5. I would like to georeference the nodes, but the image only displays as all white.

Can someone help me with this?

I have tried removing the alpha layer in Gimp, exporting as black and white, resetting the gamma, changing the background display, using stretch instead of RGB, calculating statistics. The image renders a preview in ArcCatalog but not in ArcMap.

Comment: Export to png maybe.

Comment: Already tried that. No go. The tif renders in QGIS but not in Arc. All my work is in Arc however, and I'd rather find a solution.

Comment: Can you see unique symbology?

Comment: The problem appears to be a conflict with the basemap I had included in my geodatabase. I loaded the image on a blank map and it rendered.

Comment: Have you tried applying a stretch? For example Symbology-Stretch-Standard Deviations

Comment: I'd report this as a bug to your ESRI contact - for the price you pay, you should expect it fixed very quickly.